# Parsing a string and converting embedded values to host-byte-order in Java

Tags: java, parsing, sockets

I have a java client and a C server. I server wants to send a data packet to the client containing some information in a specific order as shown below:

```
char *buf = NULL;

if(!(buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * pkt_len)))
{
        printf("Could not malloc\n");
        return -1;
}

 memcpy(buf,      &pkt_type,     2);
 memcpy(buf + 2,  &pkt_len,      4);
 memcpy(buf + 6,  &more_to_come, 1);
 memcpy(buf + 7,  &fb_id,        8);
 memcpy(buf + 15, &match,        4);
 memcpy(buf + 19, el->name,  name_len);
 memcpy(buf + 19 + name_len, "\n\r",    2);

 if(send(clientSock, buf, pkt_len, 0) < 0)
 {
     printf("Can not write to socket %d\n", clientSock);
     return -1;
 }
```

Ofcourse I have convereted all the shorts, integers and long integers to network bytes order before writing them to the buffer. The data is received as a string by the Java client. My problem is how to parse this string. For example, I would to know a way to read off the 2 bytes that indicate the pkt length and cast it to a short in host-byte-order. I am aware that Java provides a method to convert a string to an array of bytes. But what do I do after I have obtained the bytes array. Some code to perform this task would be appreciated

Comment: You should be wary when using `String`s and `byte`s interchangeably. Character encodings get involved and these can trip you up.

Comment: What are the types of the data you are sending? E.g. type of `pkt_type` and type of `match` and type of `el->name` etc. E.g. unsigned 8-bit value, or ASCII string, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?:

```
    char[] charArray = new char[2];
    charArray[0] = "a".charAt(0);
    charArray[1] = "b".charAt(0);

    String string = new String(charArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume a `char` is one byte in length here.

You could use a [DataInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html). Depending on your data types, something like the following might get you started. Note the example uses ASCII as the character encoding and doesn't try to be efficient in any way.

```
package grimbo.test.bytes;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BytesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // start setup test data
        byte[] msgStart = {
        /*pkt_type*/0, 1,
        /*pkt_len*/0, 0, 0, 1,
        /*more_to_come*/1,
        /*fb_id*/1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
        /*match*/2, 2, 2, 2 };
        String name = "John Smith\n\r";
        byte[] nameBytes = name.getBytes("ASCII");
        byte[] msg = new byte[msgStart.length + nameBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(msgStart, 0, msg, 0, msgStart.length);
        System.arraycopy(nameBytes, 0, msg, msgStart.length, nameBytes.length);
        // end setup test data

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(msg));

        new BytesTest().read(in);
    }

    void read(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
        // assuming pkt_type is an unsigned 2-byte value
        int pkt_type = in.readUnsignedShort();
        print(pkt_type);

        // assuming pkt_len is an unsigned 4-byte value
        // Java doesn't have those, so read a signed int and mask to a long
        long pkt_len = in.readInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
        print(pkt_len);

        // assuming vanilla byte is ok for this, but Java bytes are signed, not unsigned
        byte more_to_come = in.readByte();
        print(more_to_come);

        // don't know the format of this, so left as bytes
        byte[] fb_id = new byte[8];
        in.readFully(fb_id);
        print(fb_id);

        // don't know the format of this, so left as bytes
        byte[] match = new byte[4];
        in.readFully(match);
        print(match);

        char[] nr = { '\n', '\r' };
        byte[] name = readUntil(in, nr);
        print(name);
        System.out.println(">" + new String(name, "ASCII") + "<");
    }

    private byte[] readUntil(DataInputStream in, /* stop reading when these chars are found */char[] terminate)
            throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int terminateIdx = 0;
        int input = -1;
        while ((input = in.read()) > -1) {
            if (input == terminate[terminateIdx]) {
                if (terminateIdx == (terminate.length - 1)) {
                    // we've found the termination sequence
                    byte[] buf = baos.toByteArray();
                    // - terminateIdx because we don't include the termination sequence
                    byte[] result = new byte[buf.length - terminateIdx];
                    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, result, 0, result.length);
                    return result;
                }
                terminateIdx++;
            } else {
                // no match, reset count
                terminateIdx = 0;
            }
            baos.write(input);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    private void print(long l) {
        System.out.println(l);
    }

    void print(byte[] bytes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
            System.out.print(bytes[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
1
1
1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2,2,2,2
74,111,104,110,32,83,109,105,116,104
>John Smith<
```

Comment: Thank you for the reponse. However, I had some questions. What do the numbers in